# How to check that a value is not a negative number in beanshell assertion?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test that a value is not 0 or a negative number, but my test keeps coming back as passed when the number is negative. This is what I have:

```
if (value > 0) {

Failure = false;
} else {

Failure = true;
}
```

I thought less than 0 would cover minus numbers, but it seems not to? Or there is something else wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, can it be the case you have [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) with "Ignore Status" box checked?

There is nothing wrong with your code, it should work fine.

Try adding `debug();` directive as first line of your script and look into JMeter console for output or add some `log.info(...)` calls to your script to see the actual "value" of your `value` and some other helpful information like:

[image: Beanshell Assertion Debugging]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive information on using and troubleshooting your Beanshell scripts.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like my regex for extracting the response picks up any number as a positive no matter what